# object reference not set to an instance of an object in C# in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, anchor, html-agility-pack

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
//Code
}
```

this is my code where i get the exception please help me in sugesting me a solution

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: Please Post exception details. It may be that doc or doc.DocumentNode is null.

Comment: Could you please post the rest of your code where is `doc` come from?

Answer (score 4):

First stop... run the debugger and see if `doc` or `doc.DocumentNode` is null. If not, then I would check your variable instances inside the loop, including `link`.

Always try debugging before asking questions...

Answer (score 2):

make sure that doc or DocumentNode isn't null.

you can wrap your code like this.

```
if (doc!=null && doc.DocumentNode!=null)
{
     foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
      {

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try whether `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")` returns `null` or "doc" is `null`.